# Unsure how to get $_POST[''] value from form when the name is dynamic?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, hidden-field

So at the moment I have the following code which is correct but I'm just unsure how I will be able to get the `name=".$job_id."` as it will be dynamic, applicant-jobs.php below:

```
<div id="container">

<?php

foreach($jobs as $job){

$job_id = $job['id'];

echo form_open('applications/applicants'); 
echo "<div class=\"job\">";
echo $job['name'];
echo "</div>";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=".$job_id.">";
echo form_submit('submit', 'View Applicants');
echo form_close();
}

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks. P.S. I'm using codeigniter.

Comment: The variable $job_id will be different all the time. So how will I be able to get the value of this variable when it is passed onto the script ('applications/applicants'), sorry I was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, I slightly misunderstood your question. What you're looking for is the `value` attribute of the `<input>` element:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"job\" value=\"".$job_id."\">";
```

Then in PHP you just access it like:

```
$job_id = $_POST['job'];
```

Comment: I done that but then I'm like nah it can't be that easy. Seems it is, cheers.

Comment: @AyeTry if one of the answers solved your problem, please click the little check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I've been trying to click yours but I had to wait a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate arrays by key value pairs.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{

}
```

Read more on the docs here; http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Ye, but it is better to notice you just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to set the value rather than the name?
eg.

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"job_id\" value =\"".$job_id."\">";
```

Also you've got the from open and close within the loop, i think you want them outside the loop otherwise you have multiple forms and will only end up submitting one.

Comment: That's what I was originally trying to do myself but couldn't. How would I do this?

Comment: just use that line as it is... if it's not working maybe its some error with escaping all those " you can use ' without escaping them eg. echo "<input type='hidden' name='job_id' value='$job_id'>";

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, the name doesn't need to be dynamic at all. You're only using one per form.
The name can be static, and have the value dynamic.
ex:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"job_id\" value=\"".$job_id."\" />";
```

it can be accessed via $_POST['job_id']